# FRM-30049 How to change a column name in an Oracle Forms LOV Object?

Tags: oracle11g, oracleforms

Using Oracle 11g Forms 11.1.2

Compilation error reads:

```
Column Mapping: FUBAR_ID 
FRM-30049: Unable to build column mapping.
LOV WEB_PAGE_LOV Form: FORM_FUBAR 
FRM-30085: Unable to adjust form for output.
```

Column is indeed incorrect as it should be another column name(BIZZ_ID)

I see the LOV-Tree Branch, and I see the LOV objects but my inspection has not led me to any 
column names.

**Question:** How do I change the column name in an LOV Object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LOV mapping is done under the tag `LOVs`.

Here you can see all your LOVs and if you double click on it you will get the properties for this LOV.

In the `functional menu` there is an option `Column Mapping Properties`, if you click the button you will get a menu that displays the mappings.

Comment: Please make sure that the columns under LOV property 'Column Mapping Properties' matches the columns returned by the Record Group of your LOV.